# Почему Fiddler перекрывает доступ к сайтам по httpS?

Tags: http, firefox, https, proxy, прокси

Установил себе Fiddler, чтобы просматривать общение между сервером и клиентом, но после его запуска сайты, находящиеся на http**S** , выдают следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Юзаю лису.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С точки зрения информационной безопасности, Fiddler — это *man in the middle*, «человек посередине». Иными словами — злоумышленник-перехватчик.

Дело в том, что любой прокси-сервер перехватывает трафик уже после того, как тот вышел из обозревателя. Но **HTTPS как раз и был разработан, чтобы защититься от этого.**

Данная защита обеспечивается парой «ключевая пара—сертификат»:

1. *Ключевая пара* — это два ключа, один из которых шифрует трафик, другой расшифровывает. Первый известен только серверу, второй отдаётся всем желающим. Самое интересное заключается в том, что зная публичный ключ невозможно ни зашифровать трафик, ни получить закрытый, шифрующий ключ.

   Фактом использования секретного ключа сервер подтверждает своё авторство на трафик и его неприкосновенность. Если кто-то перешифрует трафик своим ключом, то на стороне клиента после расшифровки получится мусор без опознавательных знаков.
2. *Сертификат* — это специальный документ, содержащий в себе открытый ключ и указание на то, трафик с каких доменов должен им расшифровываться. Также в сертификате может содержаться информация и о владельце домена.

   Благодаря сертификатам никто не может представиться чужим сервером, так как для этого нужно обладать закрытым ключом, открытая часть которого содержится в сертификате. Более того, сам сертификат тоже зашифрован ключевой парой, на этот раз авторитетной организации, которая этот сертификат выпустила.

Так как **у Fiddler-а закрытого ключа нет**, то он при всём желании не может представиться сервером. Поэтому обозреватель (Firefox в данном случае) и бьёт тревогу о вмешательстве в канал связи.

**Выход** только один — найти и **установить дополнение непосредственно в обозреватель**. Только дополнение может работать с трафиком после его расшифровки, когда все меры безопасности уже отработали.

И нет, вы не сможете добавить исключение. Откуда компьютер может знать, что прокси запущен именно вами и только в отладочных целях? Вдруг это руткит или троянский конь, подменяющий содержимое страницы на своё, мошенническое или вредоносное?